# How do I close a Mini Program?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

This seems like a simple thing to do but I cannot find anything in the documentation about this, does anyone know how I can force a mini-program to close and return back to the super app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no way to programmatically close a Mini Program. The user will have to manually close the Mini Program using the close button on the title bar to get back to the Super App.